# An HTTP 401 unauthorized response coming form IIS 7 body is empty. ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I have a custom message I need to pass to the client when an unauthorized request is being made.

I have used the following code to pass the message value on the response body:

```
string message = baseEx.Detail.ExtraData;
return context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, message);
```

All works well on my localhost but when deploying the code on Windows Server machine with IIS 7 I get an empty response body.

I am using ASP.NET WEB API.

What might it be?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting customErrors mode="Off" in the web.config?